# How to pass Input ID (not value) from view to Controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hi I have Input array in View and I need to pass 'id' to controller. I can pass value without problem but I'm not sure how to pass IDs instead.

View

```
@foreach( $employ as $key => $item)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="{{ $item->employ_id }}" name="employee[]" value="{{ $item->employ_id }}" class="form-control" />
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Controller, I can get 'value' but not for 'id'

```
    foreach( Request::input('employee') as $key => $item ){
         echo Request::input('employee')[$key];
    }
```

Appreciated advise, possible to do that?. Thank you.

Comment: What the problem actually ? please explain, You access the id array as $request->employee nothing wrong in your code

Comment: I have input textfields that populated value from db. My concern, I need to update some field in my another table by getting some value from these textfields. So I need reference by using id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want access to both `emply_id` and the value submitted.

Change the name of your `input` to `name="employee[{{ $item->employ_id }}]"`. Then you have the `employ_id` as the key.

```
foreach( Request::input('employee', []) as $employId => $item ){
    echo 'Employ ID: ' . $employId . '<br />';
    echo 'Value: ' . $item . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure name="employee[{{ $item->employ_id }}]" will work ?

Comment: @Marwelln Two Million Thanks